# Como faço para desabilitar o template stagehand ao criar um projeto flutter web?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Já tentei desabilitar utilizando o comando `pub global deactivate stagehand` , porém não consigo criar nenhum projeto se este template não estiver habilitado. O VSCode pergunta se deseja ativá-lo usando o comando `pub global activate stagehand`.

Com este template habilitado, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro :

> Unable to execute Stagehand. Stagehand exited with code 65.
>       stagehand 3.3.2 doesn't support Dart 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.

Ao executar o `flutter doctor -v`, recebo os dados abaixo:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 6.1.7601], locale pt-BR)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at c:\flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (10 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\abel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\bin\java
    X Cannot execute C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\bin\java to determine the version

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code (version 1.36.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.2.0

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

Alguma idéia ?

Comment: Eaí, Abel! Quando foi que você instalou o Flutter, já tem tempo ou foi hoje também?

Comment: Recentemente eu tive que remover o dart e também o VSCode.. mas o flutter havia sido instalado já há algum tempo sim.

Comment: Ah, sim. Chegou a dar uma olhada na minha resposta?

Comment: Dei sim George.. não tive como validá-la ainda.. mas vou testar ela ativando o stagehand para a versão que tenho do dart e ver se funciona. Funcionando te dou um Ok. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A mensagem erro diz que o Stagehand 3.3.2 não suporta a versão 2.3.0 do dart, que é a que você tem instalada. Olhando no GitHub a pubspec do Stagehand, vi que a versão mínima do Dart é 2.4.0.

Você poderia atualizar a versão do Dart com o comando:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Outra opção seria usar uma versão mais antiga do Stagehand com suporte à versão do Dart que você já tem instalada, que no caso poderia ser a 3.2.0. Para isso, pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
pub global activate stagehand 3.2.0
```

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo.. Após tentar criar um novo projeto, o dart solicita a atualização para a versão mais recente. "Stagehand needs to be updated with 'pub global activate stagehand' to use this feature."

Comment: @AbelSouzaMagalhaes no caso, se você atualizar o flutter e o dart, você já pode usar a versão mais recente do stagehand, de acordo com os docs. (não cheguei a testar aqui ainda)

Comment: George, infelizmente não deu certo.. Atualizei o Dart para a versão 2.4 .. e depois para a versão 2.5 (dev) e mesmo assim apresenta o mesmo erro. Muito estrano a comunidade não estar relatando esse erro.